# Unable to get_the_content(); of a post in Wordpress via AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery

I'm trying to ajaxify my Wordpress theme and I use the [ajax-in-WordPress method](http://web-profile.com.ua/wordpress/dev/ajax-in-wordpress/) and I'm now trying get_the_content of post via functions.php. Using jQuery, when I do alert(data) I get the 'title' echo but not the content of the existing post I want (returns 0).

What am I doing wrong?

The jQuery part

```
$('.ajaxed,.ajaxed a,.menu-item-home a,.menu-item-object-page a').live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var toRemove = MySettings.url;
        var rewritepath = link.replace(toRemove,'');
        var handler = function(data) {
            $('title').html($('title', data).html());
            $('#primary').html($('#primary', data).html());
            $('#primary').hide().fadeIn('slow');
            $.address.title(/>([^<]*)<\/title/.exec(data)[1]);
        };
        $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
            action: 'ajax_action',
            post_id: $(this).find('input.post_id').attr('value')
        },function(data) {
            alert(data.post_title);
            alert(data.post_content);
        });
        /*$.ajax({
            url: link,
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                handler(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                handler(data, function(){
                });
            }
        });*/
        $.address.state(MySettings.path).crawlable(true).value(rewritepath);
        return false;
    });
```

The functions.php part

```
<?php
function javascripts() {
    if( !is_admin()){
        $blogurl = get_bloginfo('url');
        $thumbnail_width = get_option('thumbnail_size_w');
        $thumbnail_height = get_option('thumbnail_size_h');
        $path = parse_url(get_bloginfo('siteurl'), PHP_URL_PATH);
        $url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js';
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        if (get_transient('google_jquery') == true) {       
            wp_register_script('jquery', $url, array(), null, true);
        } 
        else {
            $resp = wp_remote_head($url);
            if (!is_wp_error($resp) && 200 == $resp['response']['code']) {
                set_transient('google_jquery', true, 60 * 5);
                wp_register_script('jquery', $url, array(), null, true);
            } 
            else {
                set_transient('google_jquery', false, 60 * 5);
                $url = get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js';
                wp_register_script('jquery', $url, array(), '1.7', true);
            }
        }
        wp_enqueue_script('plugins.js', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/js/plugins.js" , array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/js/scripts.js", array('jquery'));
        wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
        wp_localize_script('jquery', 'MySettings', array('width' => $thumbnail_width,'height' => $thumbnail_height,'url' => $blogurl,'path' => $path));
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'javascripts');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_stuff'); // ajax for logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_stuff'); // ajax for not logged in users
function ajax_action_stuff() {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'post_key', 'meta_value'); //not sure why you need this
    $post_data = get_post($post_id);
    echo json_encode($post_data);
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the entire scope of your code, it appears that you might be calling `get_the_content()` outside of the context of [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).  If so, the function doesn't understand **which** post you'd like to retrieve the content for.  Try organizing the function this way:

```
function ajax_action_stuff() {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'post_key', 'meta_value'); //not sure why you need this
    $post_data = get_post($post_id);
    $title = $post_data->post_title;
    $content = $post_data->post_content;
    echo $title;
    echo $content;
}
```

Here we've used [get_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) to return an object with all of the post data.

The jQuery function you've created...

```
function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

... should essentially contain a string in the `data` object that contains your title and content.

Here's a recommendation though, on how you can return your data in a more organized fashion, if you like.

The 'data' object (which is what you've echoed in the php function `ajax_action_stuff()`) is just a string value.  The problem though is that the data isn't really structured in a way for jQuery to fully understand and use to its full potential.  If you change your php function to return a JSON object though, then you can use all your properties in jQuery individually.  I'll show you how...

```
function ajax_action_stuff() {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'post_key', 'meta_value'); //not sure why you need this
    $post_data = get_post($post_id);
    echo json_encode($post_data);
}
```

Then in the jQuery function you have access to each property like this:

```
$.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
    action: 'ajax_action',
    post_id: $(this).find('input.post_id').attr('value')
},function(data) {
    alert(data.post_title);
    alert(data.post_content);
});
```

Have a look at the [get_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) function to see all of the properties that you have available to you.

Comment: I've updated the question, added the more code and infos... I get undefinied as results (2 alert box).

Comment: Let's see if we can figure out where the breakdown is happening... If you use Firefox and Firebug, open the Console tab and make sure Console is enabled.  Then click on your anchor that triggers an AJAX call.  You should see a new post and response in the console with your request.  Does the post data include all of the data you expect? What about the response?  You should see the post_id variable and value in your post, and also the JSON encoded response which has all of the post data.  Are you getting that far?

Comment: The anchor is the title... sorry ;-)

Comment: Ah, I see one issue is that we aren't actually passing a post id like we think we are.  Notice the line that reads `post_id: $(this).find('input.post_id').attr('value')`.  In your page I don't see any input with a class of post_id.  So jQuery tries to get that value and can't find it.  And it ends up not passing anything to PHP.

Comment: OK thank you so much... I now see the JSON response but still get undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't telling `get_the_content()` which post to retrieve the content for.  Internally, this function checks for the global `$post` object and filters the content of that object.

So change your ajax function to something like this:

```
function ajax_action_stuff() {
    global $post;

    $post_id = $_POST[ 'post_id' ];
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_key', 'meta_value' );

    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    $title = 'title';
    $content = get_the_content();

    echo $title;
    echo $content;
}
```

This will use the ID you've passed in to query the database for a specific post and populate the global `$post` object.  Now, `get_the_content()` and even `get_the_title()` should function normally.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get: 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 279